# How to mark specific data points in matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot that I want to mark some values of x on the graph like in the following image, (p.s. I put the dots by hand)

[image: see the plot]

I tried the following code, yet it did not work as I have expected.

```
roots = [-1,1,2]
plt.plot(vals,poly,markevery=roots,label='some graph')
```

As a wrap up, I want to put a dot on the function line which indicates that point is the root.

Comment: You cannot use `markevery` to obtain the desired plot, unless you know that `-1,1,2` are actually in `vals`. So first, create a [mcve] as usual when asking a question here. Next, are the values in `vals` or not? Are `vals` and `poly` python lists, sets or numpy arrays? Finally, do you know the positions of those values inside `vals` or not?

Comment: Vals and poly are python lists where they represent x and y values of the plot. Vals ranges from -60 to 60. As for the roots question, they are in vals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the `vals` are integers in the range of `[-60,60]`, one would need to find the positions of `[-1,1,2]` in that list and use those positions as the argument to `markevery`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals,poly = range(-60,60), range(-60,60)

plt.plot(vals, poly, label='some graph')
roots = [-1,1,2]

mark = [vals.index(i) for i in roots]
print(mark)
plt.plot(vals,poly,markevery=mark, ls="", marker="o", label="points")

plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could also just plot only those values,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals,poly = range(-60,60), range(-60,60)

plt.plot(vals, poly, label='some graph')
roots = [-1,1,2]

mark = [vals.index(i) for i in roots]

plt.plot(roots,[poly[i] for i in mark], ls="", marker="o", label="points")

plt.show()
```

[image]