# How to add extra information points to a Matplotlib plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

So I want to plot a Matplotlib plot `x` versus `y`, but now at certain `x` points I want to add a dot or a small circle with another value `z` written beside it.

Basically the curve depends on 3 variables and I want to plot it with 2 variables but at certain points I want to add a circle or a dot telling us about the `z` at that point. Also, note there will be multiple plots, thus the `z` circle or dot has to be of the same colour.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question? What did you try so far?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the question is in the title..ok modified the body

Comment: How in the world is this a broad question? Just a simple problem of adding some labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028674/6361531  Look at this solution to see if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For the labelling, you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate("text", (x, y) )` to annotate a specific point (x,y) with text.

Please check out this resource for definition & examples: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-annotate

To mark certain points, you need to use the `markevery` argument in `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`. You can also customize the look of the marker with the `marker` argument.

Please check out this excellent answer for more info: [How to mark specific data points in matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211866/how-to-mark-specific-data-points-in-matplotlib-graph?rq=1)

I hope all of this was helpful!