# matplotlib: apply marker only to start point or end point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib and I am struggling with style attributes.
How to add a marker only to the start point or end point of a 3D line and not on both sides?

Comment: You could use a single-point scatter plot

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to mark specific data points in matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211866/how-to-mark-specific-data-points-in-matplotlib-graph) - using `[0]` or `[-1]` for the `markevery` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`markevery`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html?highlight=markevery) parameter when plotting.

Example from the [Parametric Curve](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.5/gallery/mplot3d/lines3d.html#parametric-curve) example in the Gallery (version 2.2.5).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Prepare arrays x, y, z
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)

l = ax.plot(x, y, z, marker='o', label='parametric curve both ends', markevery=[0,-1])
l = ax.plot(x+1, y+1, z, 'r', marker='o', label='parametric curve one end', markevery=[0])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

---

I used the example from version 2.2.5 because I don't have 3.2 installed.  *Making* a 3d axis changed in 3.something - [3.2 example link](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/mplot3d/lines3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-lines3d-py).

---

[Axes.plot markevery parameter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery)

Comment: thanks a lot. markevery=[0] was the answer for my problem